# Does mysql command line have macros?

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to select a custom list of fields with my queries without typing it all each time.

For example, I might want:

```
select A, A+B, (A div 2) / C, concat_ws(' ', A, B, C, D)
from my_table where blahblahblah
```

I'm going to replace `blahblahblah` with many different conditionals but is there a way to just type

```
select MY_CUSTOM
from my_table where A > 2 and G is not null;
```

1. `select *` from a view doesn't work since I still want to query based on fields I don't want to display
2. I don't really want to do a stored procedure.. where the syntax would be like

   ```
   do_my_query('where A>2 and G is not null')
   ```

Comment: The downvote on this question is totally undeserved! It's a legitimate question, and the OP has obviously done their homework. This is why StackOverflow gets a bad reputation as intolerant.

Comment: So, @Bill, why would you not _upvote_ it as I have? :-) I consider it useful since I'm often after ways to "optimise" my development effort.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.. I might just stick with a mac terminal keyboard shortcut to paste that big select statement in.. but I'll leave this question open for a couple more days just to see if there are other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the `mysql` command program itself, but there's nothing to stop you using (for example) the shell to provide that functionality, such as (in `bash`):

```
for name in Pax Bob ; do
    echo "select * from people where name = '${name}'" | mysql ...
done
```

In your specific case, you could opt for a shell script `smc` that went something like this:

```
echo "select MY_CUSTOM from my_table $1" | mysql --user=x --password=y db
```

and call it with:

```
smc "where A>2 and G is not null"
```

although it may be prudent to add some debugging, and make sure access is granted only to those you trust not to try SQL injection attacks :-)

Comment: That's not bad in general, but for my needs.. I'd prefer 1) to stay in mysql since i'm doing other queries as well, and 2) the bash output don't seem to deal with tabs very well since it's misaligned, but that one i can probably fix with a little more work in the script.

Answer (score 1):

No, to answer your question straight, there are no macros in MySQL.

The closest thing is, as you know, a `VIEW`. But you would have to include in the view's select-list all the bare columns that you might want to write conditions on. Then just *don't* use `SELECT *` on the view; select only the columns you want.

```
CREATE VIEW my_table_enhanced AS
 SELECT *, A+B AS expr1, (A DIV 2) / C AS expr2, CONCAT_WS(' ', A, B, C, D) AS expr3
 FROM my_table;
```

Then

```
SELECT expr1, expr2, expr3
FROM my_table_enhanced
WHERE ...conditions...
```

It's usually bad practice to use `SELECT *` in production code anyway.

Comment: Yeah this wouldn't be for production, just my one-off manual queries.  Also, with this solution, I'd be tempted to name the columns q,w,e,r,t,y,u to make typing it out easier, but the problem there is the column headers would be that and not easily interpreted. Similarly, I guess I can make a view with 1 super concat field that has everything, so i can just do "select x from my_view where.." but it would have the same column header disadvantage

Comment: I really don't think the length of column names should be a big bottleneck for your developer productivity. How many times do you expect to be writing queries to reference these columns? Don't you know how to use copy & paste?